# What to use for microservices inter-communications .NET

Tags: .net, design-patterns, microservices

Doing some research on splitting our monolith into micro-services and trying to understand/determine the best way for communications between services, or if I should even be communicating between services?

Should each micro-service be a web service that only serves Http or should I be using a service bus to pass work requests around?

Comment: Regardless of these technical questions, the most important question to ask is have you defined the boundaries around the bits you are going to start splitting out?

Comment: @tomredfern Roughly but not well defined yet. I've been sub-tasked to research this without a lot of details unfortunately. Just from my reading, I'm seeing conflicting views on how communication should be done, if at all. Sorry for the vagueness

Comment: My point is that the questions you are asking around how communication should be done are premature. You have to first know exactly which capabilities you are going to carve out of the monolith. Defining your services composition is the single most important and hardest part of a microservices project, and the one which most people don't do properly

Comment: Once you've composed your services properly it should become more obvious which communication methods you will require in order that the service be able to perform it's capability

Comment: @tomredfern Thanks for the advice Tom. I'll start working on getting those details ironed out 1st now. I guess I still have the question of, is it general best practice that micro-services don't communicate directly to one another? If they do is that considered an ESB and not a micro-service?

Comment: "or if I should even be communicating between services" - if you need then yes; in general, most of the microservices communicate between them using REST or Asynchronous event-based communication

Comment: Your question is in fact "should microservices integrate? and if yes then how?"

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU I believe you are correct.

Comment: @user3953989 microservices are just SOA with a modern name, before some vendors started promoting their brokers as ESBs. The same is happening today, as some vendors are starting to push API Gateways that do what those brokers renamed as ESBs used to do. So, the very same patterns and considerations apply.

Comment: @user3953989 for example - it's not REST *or* Service Bus. A service bus can communicate with SOAP or REST services just fine. Besides, why limit things to *these*? Are *agents* like those found in Service Fabric microservices or not?

Comment: @user3953989 your question isn't "should microservices integrate?" That's an obvious *yes*, otherwise why use more than *one* service? Someone obviously needs to call other services. The question is *who should perform the integration? The client? An intermediary? Or should services know of each other?* The answer to this depends on your specific business case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... if I should even be communicating between services?

They communicate if they need and in most cases they do need. So, there is communication between microservices and between an `API Gateway` or a Client (web browser, mobile application, desktop application) and microservices. In any case, *the communication is done using the network*.

> Should each micro-service be a web service that only serves Http or should I be using a service bus to pass work requests around?

You are asking how should they communicate.

There are two types of communication:

1. synchronous, i.e. request-response; the most typical usage in between the Client and the `API gateway` or a microservice; in this type the client send a request and waits for the response; its the simplest but less scalable or resilient; *be aware of cascading failures* in nested calls between multiple microservices;
2. asynchronous, i.e. event-based; the Client does not wait for the response and it is notified when the operation succeeds or fails; this is more complex but it is more scalable and it is used by [resilient systems](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/).

Then, depending on the protocol, there are at least the following types of communication:

1. [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)
2. [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) - recommended specially with HATEOAS
3. [Publish-subscribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)

You can read more [here](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033158.do) and [here](https://www.nginx.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Building_Microservices_Nginx.pdf).

Comment: Your answer is good but slightly misleading. I would disagree that asynchronous means event based. Asynchronous just means the caller doesn't wait for a response. What gets sent is not necessarily an event. It can be a request, a command, a document, anything. Similarly, I don't agree that request-response is a synchronous pattern. It can be very easily implemented using one-way channels.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Thank you. This helps clear up my understanding of these concepts. Sounds like on the back-end I'd want to use some type of RPC like .net remoting for speed for back-end service to service communications and add an API facade for whatever needs to be exposed and possibly a gateway API in front of all the exposed micro-services.

I also assume either sync or async could be implemented for RPC, REST, or pub/sub methods and best practice would be using something like RabbitMQ to send messages via RPC between services?

Comment: I do not recommend `RPC`. The coupling is too high and also, it masks remote calls to look like local calls when the fact that the network is involved is very important. Consider using  `REST` over `HTTP`

Comment: Again i must disagree with your assertion. RPC results in a similar level of coupling as any direct call, regardless if its a standard http call or a command message sent over a service bus. The coupling is inherent in the callers expectation that the call will be processed. How is RPC any different?

Comment: I must disagree with you :) Pages 46 to 49 from https://www.amazon.com/Building-Microservices-Sam-Newman/dp/1491950358/ref=pd_sim_14_29?ie=UTF8&dpID=5156gHBSxaL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR122%2C160_&refRID=0081XVQGTK2AQ54GQ21P contain my arguments

Comment: Thanks for the reference. So can you please summarise why RPC results in higher coupling than a rest http call or an async command?

Comment: It's about brittleness; in some `RPC` implementations, `Java RMI` for example, when you want to modify the interface by adding a new `method` you then have to regenerate the stubs and you must upgrade all the clients, including the ones that do not use/care about the new `method`

Comment: This is just one example, you could also modify the structure of objects and have the same problem. This is manageable but to a point. `RPC` is not absolute bad, but I would avoid it. You can use it but be sure that you know all these.

Comment: Any breaking change to a resource, the result will be consumers of the resource have to change regardless of how they interact with the resource. That's unavoidable. You may be correct in that there may be more work involved in changing with certain technologies, but this diverts from the current discussion. The coupling is the same. To regard such coupling as bad is not correct. A high degree of coupling between providers and consumers is to be expected.

Comment: "Any breaking change to a resource" - yes, but: If you use `REST` you just ignore the fields that you do not use. Adding methods/fields is a `breaking change` for `RPC` but not for `REST`. And I haven't said anything about `HATEOAS` yet. With `HATEOAS`@`REST` you decouple even more.

Comment: The default ability to ignore added fields in a message is a property of most, if not all, serializers. If you add a new field to a type exchanged over a rpc-style call the result is the same. Added fields will be ignored, removed fields will cause a failure. Modification of RPC operation signatures is difficult, sure, but comparable with switching HTTP operations in REST. So I still can't see much difference